# appsettings.json and azure function by timer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am pretty a new at azure function development
and I a not really understand how configuration for azure function, especially for local development
I need to set up some parameters at configuration and use them at my code
I have appsettings.json and local.settings.json

I added *IConfiguration configuration* as parameter to constructor to some my class
and try to get value by calling
*_configuration["MyVar"]*

but values are always null. (like it not read appsettings.json)

that is the best practice to get/set some parameters values for local test and use them after on azure side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended way to read App settings in Azure functions(in App Service) is:

```
var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("your_key_here");
```

*Check out this article for detailed explanation: [Azure — Reading application settings in Azure Functions (ASP.NET Core)](https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-reading-application-settings-in-azure-functions-asp-net-core-1dea56cf67cf)*

Answer (score 3):

You can set your configuration values in [local.settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file) for debugging and in the Function AppSettings in Azure Portal for when it's deployed. If you want to use a custom appsettings file, you need a [FunctionStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources) class.

You won't be able to configure the trigger bindings in the appsettings file, you'll have to use the Function AppSettings for that. Please see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66439504/7520309) for more details.